# How to test an update process prior to release?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, updating

Is there a way to simulate the update of an app from Version 1 to 2?

I am not sure about what happens when I build & run an application in Xcode. I believe that when the app is already installed in the simulator, an update is happening just like it does when the user downloads a new version from the App Store. For example sqlite3 database files remain intact when I hit Bild & Run, while the binary of the app itself gets replaced.

So the question is: Is THIS already a safe way of testing update procedures? What are the alternatives PRIOR to releasing the app and getting dozens of bad reviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you change a saved file, it remains as it was. If you really want to test this, then just install the current/old version on a test device. Then build the new version onto the same device. This has the same effect as an update through iTunes for the users.

Comment: So the updating process while buildung and running works different on the simulator and on the device?

Comment: Possibly. Certain files and storage places for them are not accessible from the simulator. Most things work fine, but there are exceptions, so it really depends on what you're writing and to where.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a separate test team that doesn't have access to the xcode project, they can still test updates using the xcode organizer:

1. Install the old version of the app on your device and use it a bit to simulate real user behaviour
2. Install your provisioning profile on the device
3. Open the xcode organizer and drag the new copy of your app onto the device

That'll keep the existing data intact, allowing you to test the new app with data from the old version.